# Best way to reply to an email message for appointment

Tags: sentence-construction

Best way to reply an email to pass below message to management

"You can plan the discussion as per your convenience except time slot 9:30 AM-10:30 Am as we have daily client call in this "

Comment: There cannot be one answer. But, you may bank on user3169's answer! However, I'd not use 'between' there.

Answer (score 1):

> You can plan the discussion **at** your convenience, except **between** 9:30 AM-10:30 AM as we have **a** daily client call **at that time**.